# Increase voltage on PCI serial port

Tags: serial-port, voltage

I have many serial based cash drawers. An issue that I continually face with them is firing the latch strongly enough to open the drawer. I believe there is a capacitor that must be charged and if the capacitor is not charged enough then when the latch fires it fails to open. (You can still hear a weak 'click' sound, but the drawer does not open.)

From experience, (not direct measurement), I can tell that main-board serial ports must have higher voltage than peripheral (PCI) serial ports. For this reason, I always put cash drawers on the main-board serial port, and printers on peripheral ones. The problem is then almost completely fixed and you'll only fail to open the drawer if you try twice in too short a time.

When using a peripheral serial port, I can usually only open the drawer if I let the capacitor charge for something like 20-30 seconds; and then, the port must be open in the program that is using it as well. If a program opens the port, sends a signal, and then closes the port, the drawer will never open. (So the voltage is only there when the port is open, I guess.) This means that one option is to change the program to keep the port open all the time, and then hopefully it will have enough time in between usages to fully charge.

I now am faced with a situation where I have a computer with *only* peripheral serial ports, and implementation of sending the cash drawer signal is up to me. My two options right now are: keep the port open 100% of the time, or use a different computer and/or motherboard.

What would be nice instead is if there was a way to just fix the problem with the PCI cards. Is there a way to increase the voltage on the PCI serial port cards? Or maybe, is keeping a serial port connection open for the lifetime of a program not necessarily a problem? (It feels to me like bad practice and something to be avoided if possible.) Maybe there is some other option that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Why are you fixated on voltage (which apparently you haven't even bothered to measure)?  How do you know it's not an issue of  limited current (e.g. line transceivers could limit current to 10 mA)?  Essentially you're asking a XY question based on your (probably faulty) assumptions.

Comment: @sawdust if you have a reason to think I'm wrong, let me know. if it's current and not voltage, the question remains: is there a way to increase it so that the drawer will work reliably?

Comment: *"I can tell that main-board serial ports must have higher voltage than peripheral (PCI) serial ports"* -- All serial ports are peripherals, whether integrated on the motherboard or in silicon of a SoC.  Be accurate & more specific.  The voltage *sources* for RS-232 signals will differ depending on motherboard versus PCI expansion board versus PCI-X expansion board versus USB adapter.  Are you a human voltmeter?  You have the equipment in front of you; it's foolish to be guessing instead of actually measuring.  Measuring DC voltage is easy; measuring small current is more effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear answering this question because it is kind of a product recommendation, which is off topic.

Your assumptions are correct, and RS232 states that the voltage for signalling is roughly [3v to 15v](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215) (positive for a 0, negative for a 1) and it is quite common for RS232 communications to use 4v-8v in budget add-on cards like most of those that are 1655x UART based.

I am assuming by "opening the port" the applications is raising a hardware handshaking line like DTR or something, which is only raised for a moment to pull your contact or open your relay. Not the best way to do this but that isn't the point of your question.

It is common for mainboard serial ports to use the 12v line for signaling, yielding ~11v measured to most applications, well most PCI cards use the 5v line for signaling and signal from 5v to 12v (it is REALLY hard to find this information in technical specs), and quality USB to Serial adapters (like the Digi Edgeport) provide about 9v according to [Digi](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/How-many-volts-do-Edgeports-output-on-the-serial-pins/?q=Edgeport%20USB%20%E2%80%93%20All%20model%20USB-to-serial%20converters&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1)'s FAQ.

I think what you are looking for is a PCI serial card with "power output" or "switchable power output", similar to this [Startech PCI 4-port card](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Serial-Cards-Adapters/4-Port-PCI-RS232-Serial-Card~PCI4S954PW) or this [Startech PCI Express 2 port card](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Serial-Cards-Adapters/2-Port-PCI-Express-Serial-Card~PEX2S553S). For comparison purposes (I am not saying Startech is the answer), there is another example from Siig [CyberSerial Dual 950 PCI](http://www.siig.com/it-products/serial-parallel/serial/pci/cyberserial-dual-950-pci.html) that might work for you. A lot of 1695x UART based cards have this switchable output, but not all, most of them have a separate power connector from the power supply.

I work with serial communications all the time in the hospitality and health care industry, basically we have found "cheap" cards don't cut it, and some research and selecting the proper enterprise/industrial grade product pays for itself after a while.

I am not positive cards like this will fix your problem, but it is quite likely as we have had similar situations and using similar devices has corrected issues like this.

Comment: The "power ouput" on those cards has nothing to do with the RS-232 signal voltage levels.  It's a constant voltage for *power*, and not a signaling voltage. *"Your assumptions are correct..."* -- Not likely.

Comment: @sawdust Care to provide more details why you believe the assumptions made are incorrect, and (assuming it was you) you down-voted the answer rather then just comented?  The answer strikes me as being quite reasonable, written by someone with at least some knowledge, and it would seem reasonable that power would increase with voltage [ provided current does not drop, similarly a better quality card could probably provide a higher current ]

Comment: thanks. I don't think it's a product recommendation question, because that doesn't have to be the answer (maybe there is a jumper or other settings to toggle voltage). knowing that PCI devices and serial devices will vary in what voltages they use helps; that is precisely what I needed to know.

Comment: *I fear answering this question because it is kind of a product recommendation, which is off topic.*...You're fine. **Questions** soliciting product recommendations are off-topic. Answers recommending products are not off-topic, so long as they provide some basic details and explain *why/how* the product answers the OP's question.

Comment: *"most PCI cards use the 5v line for signaling and signal from 5v to 12v"* -- That seems unlikely since PCI has +12V and -12V supply lines.  Don't know about *"most"*, but I have a PCI board w/two RS-232 ports, and it does use the +12V & -12V supplies available from the PCI bus.  Note that PCI-X does not have a +5V supply.